# Is there any virus that deletes Personal Folder?

Tags: virus, deletion

I noticed that some special folders of my ex-HDD have been deleted. 'Personal' is one of them.

Is there any virus that does that?

Comment: Why do you have your ex's HDD with you? Also, yes, it's possible that a malware can do that. However, it's much more likely that you, or someone you know, has deleted the file manually.

Comment: Is there any way to know that it is done by virus or no?

Comment: Virus scan your PC?

Comment: @JalalJaberi Post festum? Highly unlikely.

Comment: @ScottHelme: Yes, I am using Symantec and last thread it shows is W32.Dromedan. But in this virus there is no deletion behavior.

Comment: @Adnan: If I could know about delete time, maybe I could guess. No way to know this too?

Answer (score 2):

There are viruses available which can delete things.  Most viruses these days don't annoy the user anymore, instead it tries to use your machine to make money by participating in click-scam botnets or are used to steal your personal information. In both cases it's in the best interest of the virus to keep undetected and thus not start to remove random folder. Hence, as @Adnan pointed out it's more likely that in fact you accidentally did this yourself.

There is a chance that you can still recover these files using file recovery tools (depending on the filesystem of your hard drive and also depending if you have written files to this drive as this will destroy your data). You can always have a shot at [NTFS undelete](http://ntfsundelete.com/)

If you are still convinced that you are indeed affected by a virus, you could use a Kaspersky live disk to scan your machine while it's switched off. If you are still convinced after scanning that some virus has deleted your files you should re-install your computer completely (Nuke it from orbit) and restore it from a last known good backup.

For future reference I would seriously advice you to consider making periodic  backups of your important files as to avoid accidental deletion.